# jQuery: Select to find last li of nested lists

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery selector to find the last li of several nested lists. The structure will be deeper than this in reality, but I figure a selector that could get these two should probably work.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>some link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>not this one</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>this one</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a>also not this one</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>and this one too</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about `<a>some link</a>`? It's inside a LI which is the last (and only) LI in its UL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li:last-child > a');
```

Will select every `<a>` element, which is a child of the last `<li>` of every `<ol>` or `<ul>` list.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Et5wv/

Comment: +1, although this also catches the first `some link`, to exclude that you'd need `ul ul li:last-child > a`

Comment: This was basically correct, I made the mistake of indirectly indicating I wanted the links to be the return items when I actually wanted the li itself. And Rory was correct I didn't want the top level included, but got me to where I needed.